# Django inserts wrong domain to activation email, facebook auth and filebrowser

Tags: django, facebook, django-authentication

I've set up a Django project on a nginx server. But..

1. Django detects `request.get_host()` in signup and activation views as `localhost` and sends email (for activation and password reset) with links like `http://localhost/...`.
2. I've set up Facebook authorization via `social-auth-app-django`. But Facebook tries to open redirect_uri in `localhost` 
   (`...redirect_uri=http:localhost/oauth/complete/facebook...`)
3. Inside django admin TinyMCE editor Filebrowser also refers to `localhost`..

How to fix these problems? Or it seems one solution can fix all of them.

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried changing your Site.domain and Site.name in admin panel or via shell? `from django.contrib.sites.models import Site`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/sites/

It's used in many cases such as emails by default.

Comment: Changed `example.com` to my domain. But still not works. 
Facebook still tries to open `redirect_uri` in localhost. 
Both `get_current_site(request)` and `request.get_host()` inserts `localhost` in production.

Comment: Add this to your django settings 'USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True'  it replace it's internal address by external address, it's needed when your backend is called from nginx, which address is localhost.

Comment: Thank you so much! it works (with setting `proxy_set_header` in nginx).